Invalid transaction & Transaction has a bad signature
I'm trying to adjust my implementation to the recent runtime changes
CheckMetadataHash. I added the mode in the transaction and both the metadatahash and the mode parameter in the payload that is sign but the extrinsic that's now broadcasted returns a bad signature.
example payload
0x050000b64876eed630b7cfdb23ae4e4a92c311a322a871c04b99675e8d4a97286c733702286bee25009c0000164a0f001a00000091b171bb158e2d3848fa23a9f1c25182fb8e20313b2c1eb49219da7a70ce90c383f3065398421a9fee9a14be6d44c3c2a57838800494b96eb44866d6a50ae0dc00
submitted extrinsic
0x3d028400b64876eed630b7cfdb23ae4e4a92c311a322a871c04b99675e8d4a97286c7337017a00249a6765b338d1d0544bc69da5a2f7261e9f7a2c054898ff7c96f76ea61653b8d6cad481cc222b7a38053e3abc199ac007aa13562b44a38dfeb65860358c25009c0000050000b64876eed630b7cfdb23ae4e4a92c311a322a871c04b99675e8d4a97286c733702286bee
Basically, my setup worked before the upgrade for sending DOT, KSM and other related transaction like staking but now it's broken.
What do you think I'm missing?

Could you resolve this issue since you reported it?

Check if this answer could be related to yours as well: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/11886/318
